# How do I hide a REST API Url from the end user?

Tags: javascript, rest

Is it possible to hide my REST URL that I using via AJAX to populate page data? I don't want others taking and consuming from my REST API, but need to use it to display content in my site.

How do I hide my REST API URLs from the end user?

Comment: No its not. Even if you obscure it nicely in the  code, the guy can simply check the requests tab to see what url is called.

Comment: No, it's not possible to hide that url - but you can use url-shortener to "obfuscate" it. If the user shouldn't know about the content of that site, use other mechanisms like a login

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not possible to hide the URL From the end user in JavaScript. They can simply open up the Network panel in Chrome, or just turn on Fiddler to see it.

In your particular case, the only real way you can hide the URL from the user is to proxy the REST call to your API from your server-side code.

If you must use JavaScript, you can always create and use APIKeys and simply monitor their usage and terminate API Keys that are taking up too much bandwidth; but again -- this isn't going to stop someone from being able to use your API, it'll just let you know when you receive an unexpected amount of traffic from unexpected places.

You could take it further by cycling API keys every day, so if someone wants to use your API; they have to change their code every day -- but again, this won't stop someone, just slow them down.

The only fullproof way is the way I mentioned in my first paragraph -- but that can't be done from client-side JavaScript alone.

#### Update in the age of Single Page Applications

What I wrote holds true, even for Single Page Applications (SPA); though you can hide the URL in the *address bar* by having different routing for your client-side application than your server-rendered pages.

The user can still inspect the traffic in their browser's console to check where the requests are going (there's no getting around that), but you can at least display different paths in the address bar.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I guess the ends of having JSON data from REST justify the means of exposing the URL.

Answer (score 6):

Not really. **The page needs to have access to the URL in order to use it, and this gets you into the age-old problem of showing somebody something while hiding it from them at the same time**. Modern browsers with built-in debugging tools compound the problem: even if you encrypt the URL, there comes a point where you will have to decrypt it in order to use it, and debuggers can jump in at that point.

Is there a particular reason that you're concerned about others using the API? There isn't really a way to prevent others from finding the URL, but there may be other ways to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to hide the url from anyone with the motivation and determination to find it. It is not advisable to depend on security by obscurity and everything exposed via REST should be considered a potential vulnerability and all necessary security checks made on the server side. Treat all REST APIs just as you would a public web page.

Answer (score 1):

By hiding I'm assuming you mean not having any association to the URL shown in your Javascript. Unfortunately it's not possible to hide the URL as far as I know, even if you managed to hide it in javascript, the request would be visible in any extension capable of picking up outgoing and incoming http requests on a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending request for json data send request for the whole html rendered data in the api call. in this way hiding of the json data will also get managed and the rendering time of your page will also get speed up. no need of json data calls on client side.

Comment: this is also harder for hacker to parse than structured json

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering the HTML server-side (if you think you have high server capacity). If the HTML is pre-rendered the API calls are not visible to the end user.

If you are using:

1. React - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/server-side-rendering-your-react-app-in-three-simple-steps-7a82b95db82e/
2. Angualar - https://angular.io/guide/universal

Frameworks like Django by default do server side rendering.

-> Server side rendering may cause load on the server compared to client-side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, maybe a different interpretation of hiding the api but indeed hiding it from direct access nevertheless. I assume that's the point of hiding it anyway.

You can do it through your web server. I'm using Nginx. I have an if statement that checks the $http_referer. If there isn't one, or if it's not being made by my application/frontend page (meaning someone is trying to hit the api directly), it'll return a 403 forbidden page.

If your application doesn't send out emails to your users don't worry about the following: I added a block to allow access to my static images as the only exception, as my application sends out emails with images and I don't want them to break.

That's it. Problem solved. No one has access to my api except my frontend page/application.

So yes, the api is hidden from the user as in they can try to hit it if they want to but they won't be able to get in.