# How do I secure web API of my public website?

Tags: security, .net-core, webapi

I have a public website developed using dot net core 3.0 which anyone can access. It basically allow users to search key information about a place.
So whenever user Search for any place I store the place information in SQL
But I am confused, how do I secure my web API. As anyone can see my JS and page source. And figure out API endpoint. Then any one can hit it using postman.
I have already configured HTTPS but is there anything I can do to secure it?

Comment: You can’t. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24866357/16587

Comment: The only way to secure it is to use auth credentials like cookies or JWTs. If you keep it public, your APi is visible to end users.

Comment: Somehow render it on the serverside using a private API key?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use JWT Authentication which is simple & best to secure our application.

Visit: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api